# Select a tab bar item depending on its tag number

Tags: objective-c, tabs

I have an app which has 7 tab bar items. At some point I want to programmatically click 1 of the tab bar items . Each tab bar item has a unique tag number. I want to do something like this:

`[self.tabBarController setSelectedTag:9];`   Or get the index of a tab bar item whose tag number is 9 so that I can use it in `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:index]`. I cannot find any solution. Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over the view controllers to find the one with the tag you require, then select it. Something like this ...

```
// find the view controller
UIViewController* viewControllerToSelect;
for(UIViewController* vc in self.tabController.viewControllers) {
  if (vc.tag == tagToFind) {
    viewControllerToSelect = vc;
    break;
  }
}

// select it
self.tabController.selectedViewController = viewControllerToSelect;
```

There are more elegant ways to search, using predicates - but the above should do the trick.